# Accessing a value via dictionary

Tags: ios, json, core-data, dictionary

I use the following code to access the JSON values via coredata,

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[DataAccessLayer sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];
 NSArray *existingResults = [context fetchObjectsForEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Serchtrial class]) withSortColumn:nil withSortDescending:FALSE withPredicate:nil];
 NSLog(@"->%@",existingResults);
 Serchtrial *result;
 for(int i=0;i<[existingResults count];i++)
 {
    result=[existingResults objectAtIndex:i];
     [mydata setValue:result forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"checka%d",i]];
 }
 NSLog(@"mydata age%@",[mydata objectForKey:@"checka0"]);
```

The Log return the result as following

```
mydata age<Serchtrial: 0x8c80a10> (entity: Serchtrial; id: 0x8c81990 <x- coredata://39E99C99-5639-4C67-86D5-D9B97C79EDF2/Serchtrial/p2> ; data: {
age = "18-25";
gender = Female;
keywords = "AB-ve,o+ve";
"trial_Id" = 0;
"trial_desc" = nil;
})
```

But i want only data in single dictionary

```
data: {
age = "18-25";
gender = Female;
keywords = "AB-ve,o+ve";
"trial_Id" = 0;
"trial_desc" = nil;
}
```

What change should i made in my code,Please help to solve this.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? Right now you got an array of `Serchtrial` objects, why do you need to serialize them in dictionaries?

Comment: Serchtrial is a coredata object..

Comment: Yes that is clear from your question. But what is the _reason_ that you need it as a dictionary? You can access any property of your objects pretty much the same way you would with a dictionary.

Comment: but the coredata containts a set of value... How to retrive directly the set of value in coredata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the fetch request return dictionaries instead of managed objects, you have to set

```
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

for the `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: where should i want to mention this `[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];`

Comment: @Globastechn: Where the fetch request is created, probably inside the `fetchObjectsForEntityName:...` method. - That is not a built-in Core Data method, where does it come from?

Comment: @Globastechn: Please let me know if you need more information.